Game hosted on itch.io cannot be embedded into Next.js website
So I recently made a game on Unity and I exported the game with WebGL. I then hosted the game on itch.io and got the embed link so that I can embed the game in my website. I would like users to be able to play my game directly on my Next.js website.I added the iframe and the embed link but whenever I try and play the game it asks to redirect back to itch.io to play the game.
Is there a way to have users play the embedded game on my website and not be redirected back to itch.io to play or is there another service I could use that does not redirect me?
Thank you!
Here is my code for embed:
import React from 'react';

const GameEmbed: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen relative">
      <iframe
        src="https://itch.io/embed/2716072"
        className="w-full h-full border-none"
        allowFullScreen
        title="Unity Game"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameEmbed;



host it on your own website then

@BugFinder So would I just download the WebGL files and store it inside the public folder? Would that cause any issues with bandwidth or the site being very slow?

we  you'd upload them from your pc normally, but, as long as your website is configured correctly (unity tell you how) the speed of the website will impact the initial load time, and any streamed assets youve setup but for the most part, no.

No possible to host on itch.io, I did not know it was possible to host game files on the website itself I always assumed you needed a service like itch. Thank you for you help!
